# Change TextBox format when editing not working

Tags: wpf

I wan't to change TextBox format when editing its value.
when editing it should show something like "25",
when I stop editing it should change format to "25records".

Initial value is "25records", while I am editing it will change to "25", I am changing value to "11", but when I stop editing it is showing old value "25records". If I start editing again it will change value to "11". I am not sure where 11 is stored and why Binding hasnt changed 25 to 11??!!

```
    <TextBox Name="RefreshRecords" FontSize="25" >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding  Path=RefreshRecordsNum, StringFormat=\{0:c\}records}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding  Path=RefreshRecordsNum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it seems to work fine? Does `RefreshRecordsNum` fire a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Well done :) I was focusing soo much on Style that I havent check that.